# add rows each year in mysql with condition

Tags: php, mysql

i hav a student_class table containing the following fieds
**id,student_id,class,year**
i want after every year to add a new row containing
**id,student_id,class+1,year+1**
for row having class=4 to stop adding the new row.
i tried something like this but i don get the result i want

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

 CREATE EVENT increment_student_form
 ON SCHEDULE 
 STARTS '2013-03-22 11:45:00'
 EVERY 1 YEAR

 DO 

 $students=array();
 $class=array();
 $stud=select * from student_class where class<4;
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($stud);
    $students[]=$row['student_id'];
    $class[]=$row['class'];
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($students);$i++){

 INSERT into student class(id,student_id,class,year) values('','$student[i]','$class[i]+1','$year+1') 
 }
```

Comment: from where does $year comes from?

Comment: comes from student_class table

Answer (score 0):

Use `Begin  End` for event body

```
DO 
    Begin
    ...
    ...
    END
```

Edit 1: Also use quotes for `select` statement

```
$stud="select * from student_class where class<4";
```

Answer (score 0):

I have spotted some errors in your code

1. Your current code will fetch only first record ..mysql_fetch_array shold be in loop.
2. I cannot see $year defined anywhere.
3. The way you are mixing mysql event handling and php code is not correct.

Try Using this code

```
 $stud="select * from student_class where class<4";
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($stud))
 {
  $sql = "INSERT into student class(id,student_id,class,year) values('','{$row['student_id']}','{$row['class']}','{$row['year']}+1')" ;
  mysql_query($sql);
 }
```

I will suggest you that it will be better to use crone job for your purpose on this php script rather than mysql event handling.

Comment: it return this error      #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'STARTS '2013-03-22 11:45:00'
EVERY 1 YEAR

DO

$stud=select * from stude' at line 3

Comment: you should not mix it with mysql event handling statement .. this is just a php script .. save it in .php extension file and set up crone job on it ...

Comment: @internally1 Events will not be created ... When you set up cron job for a script .. then you dont ned to have mysql events

Comment: so how can i make the event to be created then?? coz i ned it

Comment: Your code has syntax errors because of the single quotes (Do you see how the syntax highlighting is not correct after "values"?)

Comment: @Jocelyn it was just a typo..thanks for spotting .. but why downvote.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your Problem is completely within SQL. So you arent allowed to use PHP with your SQL Query. 
Have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html for further Syntax options.
Begin with (taken out of the manual):

```
CREATE EVENT event
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 YEAR STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE 
COMMENT 'Clears out sessions table each hour.'
DO
```

This should clear your syntax problem and create an empty Event which runs every year ans starts 1 minutes after creation.
From here i can only assume the right way. Somethin like:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE @student INT = 0;
  DECLARE @class INT = 0;
  DECLARE @year INT = 0;
  DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT student_id, class, year FROM student_class WHERE class < 4;

  OPEN MyCursor;

  FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor
  INTO @student,@class,@year;
  WHILE  @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
    SET @year = @year + 1;
    SET @class = @class + 1;
    INSERT into student_class(student_id,class,year) values(@student, @class ,@year ) 
    FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @student,@class,@year;
  END
  CLOSE MyCursor;
  DEALLOCATE MyCursor;
END
```

So this SQL is completely unknown for me, i just guess this might give you enough hints to solve your problem on your own or ask a new more specific question!
Good Luck!

Comment: it returns me an error'#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'STARTS '2013-04-03 14:25:00'
EVERY 1 MINUTE

DO

$students=array()' at line 3 '

Comment: as i though this needs to be in SQL Syntax, where, AFAIK, you are not allowed to use PHP, isn't it? Well i cant help you in this regard, i am not the best SQL-Programmer. I think u need some kind of procedure to run on your event.

Comment: i completely rearranged my answer based on the new information! Give it a try ^^

Comment: i tried but it gives #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPEN MyCursor' at line 11

Comment: well as i said, i never programmed in SQL. But maybe i found some errors. Try again, but this will be as far as i can bring you. If it still doesnt work, use either a cron job with PHP or ask another question referring to this one.

Comment: am tryn the cron job with PHP now @philipp

Comment: Too bad, i was interested in the solution too... Would you mind to accept an answer though? ^^